# Getting the maximum of a row from a pyspark dataframe with DenseVector rows

Tags: python, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I have a dataframe with DenseVectors as row:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(Vectors.dense([1,2,3]),),(Vectors.dense([3,4,5]),),(Vectors.dense([6,2,5]),)], ["a"])
```

and I want to find the maximum of each row with UDF. This is what I did:

```
findmax = F.udf(lambda x: max(x),DoubleType())
df_out = df_out.select('*',findmax(df_out['sensor_data']).alias('MAX'))
```

After I ran the codes, this is the message i got

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       df.select('*',findmax(df['a'])).show()
>
> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\python2\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\dataframe.py",
>   line 336, in show
>       print(self._jdf.showString(n, 20))
>
> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\python2\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py",
>   line 1133, in **call**
>       answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
>
> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\python2\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\utils.py",
>   line 63, in deco
>       return f(*a, **kw)
>
> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\python2\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py",
>   line 319, in get_return_value
>       format(target_id, ".", name), value)
>
> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o785.showString. :
>   org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
>   Task 2 in stage 67.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task
>   2.0 in stage 67.0 (TID 890, localhost, executor driver): net.razorvine.pickle.PickleException: expected zero arguments for
>   construction of ClassDict (for numpy.dtype)   at
>   net.razorvine.pickle.objects.ClassDictConstructor.construct(ClassDictConstructor.java:23)
>     at net.razorvine.pickle.Unpickler.load_reduce(Unpickler.java:707)   at
>   net.razorvine.pickle.Unpickler.dispatch(Unpickler.java:175)   at
>   net.razorvine.pickle.Unpickler.load(Unpickler.java:99)    at
>   net.razorvine.pickle.Unpickler.loads(Unpickler.java:112)  at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.BatchEvalPythonExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(BatchEvalPythonExec.scala:156)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.BatchEvalPythonExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(BatchEvalPythonExec.scala:155)
>     at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)   at
>   scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)    at
>   scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)    at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:395)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:234)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:228)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)    at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)   at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>
> Driver stacktrace:    at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1517)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1505)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1504)
>     at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
>     at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1504)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
>     at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)   at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1732)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1687)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1676)
>     at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:630)
>     at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2029)    at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2050)     at
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2069)     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:336)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:2861)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2150)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2150)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$55.apply(Dataset.scala:2842)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:65)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:2841)  at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2150)     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2363)     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:241)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)  at
>   py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)    at
>   py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)     at
>   py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
>     at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)   at
>   py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   net.razorvine.pickle.PickleException: expected zero arguments for
>   construction of ClassDict (for numpy.dtype)   at
>   net.razorvine.pickle.objects.ClassDictConstructor.construct(ClassDictConstructor.java:23)
>     at net.razorvine.pickle.Unpickler.load_reduce(Unpickler.java:707)   at
>   net.razorvine.pickle.Unpickler.dispatch(Unpickler.java:175)   at
>   net.razorvine.pickle.Unpickler.load(Unpickler.java:99)    at
>   net.razorvine.pickle.Unpickler.loads(Unpickler.java:112)  at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.BatchEvalPythonExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(BatchEvalPythonExec.scala:156)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.BatchEvalPythonExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(BatchEvalPythonExec.scala:155)
>     at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)   at
>   scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)    at
>   scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)    at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:395)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:234)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:228)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$25.apply(RDD.scala:827)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)    at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)   at
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>   1 more

I have no idea why this wouldn't work: I found that if the rows are just floats instead of DenseVectors it will work, and the python function max accepts DenseVectors as input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this error is that you have defined the return type of udf as `float` while the udf is actually returning `numpy.float64`. pyspark treats `float` and `numpy.float64` as different types.
convert the return type to float like this.
`findmax = F.udf(lambda x: float(max(x)),DoubleType())`

Comment: Thanks! Helped a lot!